# One or multiple transactions in a single servlet request

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, servlets, transactions

What is the best practice when I have to read data from the database, make operations that can take a second or two (like calling external API) and then updating the database?

1. Should I make everything in one transaction that takes a couple of seconds?
2. Should I make one transaction for reading the data, make all the processing, and then open a new transaction for writing the data?

Comment: Are you working on a single row or multiple?

Comment: @GarimaGupta it changes. does it matter?